# Java - Calling methods from another class [ERROR]

Tags: java, class, methods

I have two classes, Main Class and Transaction Class.

Inside the Main class i want it to run a method from the Transaction class.

I've tried what I have done below but it gives me an error telling me to create a method called writeFile(), but i all ready have a method called writeFile() inside the Transaction class.

How do i do this correctly without errors?

```
public class Main(){
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Transactions trans = new Transactions();
        trans.writeFile();
    }
}
```

```
public class Transactions {

    public void writeFile() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have both these classes in same file? or do you have in separate files? If so did you compile Transactions first and then compiled your main class?

Answer (score 3):

`Main` class definition is wrong, it should be

```
public class Main
```

Instead of

```
public class Main()
```

Remove the brackets.